# При проверке сайта в админке: (check_mysql_table_structure): Fail

Tags: битрикс

при сканировании сайта через админку наткнулся на такую ошибку

```
2023-Nov-29 14:27:43 Структура базы данных (check_mysql_table_structure): Fail
ALTER TABLE `b_b24connector_buttons` CHANGE `SCRIPT` `SCRIPT` text NULL DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `b_forum_stat` CHANGE `SHOW_NAME` `SHOW_NAME` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
CREATE INDEX `ix_iblock_element_prop_val` ON `b_iblock_element_property` (value(50),iblock_property_id,iblock_element_id);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX `IXF_B_USER_INDEX_1` ON `b_user_index` (search_user_content);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX `IXF_B_USER_INDEX_2` ON `b_user_index` (search_department_content);
ALTER TABLE `b_landing` CHANGE `HISTORY_STEP` `HISTORY_STEP` int NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `b_landing_block` CHANGE `HISTORY_STEP_DESIGNER` `HISTORY_STEP_DESIGNER` int NOT NULL;
```

и не понимаю как исправить, может кто тоже сталкивался ?

Comment: В таблице `b_b24connector_buttons` тип поля `SCRIPT` меняйте на `text` `NULL` `DEFAULT NULL`. В таблице `b_forum_stat` тип поля `SHOW_NAME` на `varchar(255)` `NULL` `DEFAULT NULL` и т.д.

Comment: Большое спасибо ,  да , после того как выполнил то что вы посоветовали - ошибки ушли